alt+tab is killing my kde session - kubuntu 24.10
I upgraded to kubuntu 24.10 last night (it's actually an ubuntu where I installed kubuntu-desktop a number of releases ago and I use kde).... I don't mind the little details here or there but I just found one that is killing me. If I press alt+tab to switch between apps, UI just dies and restarts (and most of my open windows die with it, by the way)... the session is still up, some of the windows like konsole are still there and they keep their content so they did not die so it wasn't a full kde crash.... but almost. Is there an easy way to fix this?
